# Electrum Wallet (Error in signing the message

Tags: wallet

when i tried to sign my electrum wallet for byteball transition bot

an error is displayed as

*Cannot sign messages with this type of address.
Signing with an address actually means signing with the corresponding private key, and verifying with the corresponding public key. The address you have entered does not have a unique public key, so these operations cannot be performed.*

I was using bitcoin address in address and my byteball address in message. How can I solve this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is specifically for programming questions. For Bitcoin-related problems, please ask your question on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead. For further information, please refer to the documentation regarding what is considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)' for StackOverflow, and what questions [**shouldn't be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead.